# device in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, token

I am using [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2/#step-2-register-the-sample-with-your-azure-active-directory-tenant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnHRd.png) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2/#step-2-register-the-sample-with-your-azure-active-directory-tenant to generate token and I have followed the procedure as mentioned in the above link. I have provided clientID in appsetting.json file and it keeps keeping 
 **Failed to get user name** error.

I have used the admin account to generated the app.

screenshot of error:
[image: Joined with window:]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested this sample but didn't get this error. Please share a screenshot about your error. Besides, did you do anything other than create an Azure AD app and configure the client ID into the `appsettings.json` file?

Comment: I am getting this **Failed to get user name
Press any key to exit**  from this  catch (MsalClientException)

Comment: What kind of account are you using to log in? Is it an Azure AD user or personal account?

Comment: azure AD account

Comment: I have tried **https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication** too.  It is showing me that i am managed user in error. I need to be federated user and i dont know how to do it.

Comment: and i have not done anything beside creating Azure AD app and configure the client ID into the appsettings.json

Comment: It's a little strange. How about use `AcquireTokenInteractive` instead of `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` (line 93 in PublicAppUsingIntegratedWindowsAuthentication.cs file)? Have a try to see what will be returned.

Comment: After trying a microsoft sign in window prompt up and when i tried to sign in using admin username and password it giving me error of **AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '6e1adc23-6047-4601-ba16-51fc59a0ea9f'.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204866/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-user9107307).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, this issue should have been resolved. I will summarize the solution here.

As the [sample overview](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-iwa-v2#overview) says:

> This sample demonstrates how to use MSAL.NET from apps that run on a
>   domain joined or AAD joined Windows machine.

So you need to use an AAD joined Windows machine to test this sample.

Firstly, you need to [add your Windows machine into your AAD domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-join-device-on-network#to-join-an-already-configured-windows-10-device).

Then when you run this sample, you may encounter the following error: `The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '{appId}' named '{appName}'`.

This is because you haven't got user consent for this app in your AAD. You need to call `AcquireTokenInteractive` instead of `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` in line 93 in `PublicAppUsingIntegratedWindowsAuthentication.cs` file. And then call `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth` again.

Now you can get the user signed-in on the Windows machine successfully.

---

**Update:**

Based on [Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#constraints-1), IWA supports federated users only, meaning users created in Active Directory and backed by Azure AD. Users created directly in Azure AD, without Active Directory backing (managed users) can't use this authentication flow.

So if you want to use IWA(Integrated Windows Authentication), you need a federated account to test it.

Comment: thanks for the reply but as mentioned in the link [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-join-device-on-network#to-join-an-already-configured-windows-10-device) step 4. They have used contoso.com domain and i have used abc.onmicrosoft domain. Do u think it might be causing me problem.   And i connected with device with abc.onmicrosoft. is it causing me problem?

Comment: i tried your solution again but it showing me same error **Failed to get user name**. i even connected my device to azure ad but still same problem is occurring. Can you please tell me whether i to make my device hybrid or not?

Comment: @user9107307 There should be nothing wrong with if you use contoso.com or abc.onmicrosoft domain. Are you sure your machine is joined? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-join-device-on-network#to-make-sure-youre-joined-1.

Comment: Yes i  am sure and i have updated screen shot of that.

Comment: @user9107307 I think you have noticed the possible reasons before. IWA supports federated users only, meaning users created in Active Directory and backed by Azure AD. Users created directly in Azure AD, without Active Directory backing (managed users) can't use this authentication flow. My test account which has successfully result with this sample code is a federated user (I'm not the admin of the tenant, but I just get a clarification from our admin that the tenant is federated). If your account is not a federated user, you will fail to get the expected result.

Comment: @user9107307 For federated,you need to learn more about ADFS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/how-to-connect-fed-azure-adfs. It require you to have on-premise AD and scync with AAD. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can u tell me how to do it? I have tried like multiple times but failed to achieve federated user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204921/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-user9107307).